# Display data from PHP in jqplot chart

Tags: php, jqplot

i have simple php page with script where i fetch data from DB

```
$plot_row1 = array();
$plot_row2 = array();
$query1 = "SELECT date, name, value FROM list WHERE date between '$s_date' and '$e_date'      
ORDER BY date";

$result = $mysqli->query($query1);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $sum_list = $sum_list + $row['value'];
    $plot_row1[] = $row['value'];
    $plot_row2[] = $row['date'];
}
```

Then I would like to have jqplot chart where X axis consists of dates from $plot_row2[] and Y axis contains values from $plot_row2[]

I started with the following code and what I need is to somehow prepared the values (in PHP) in the appropriate way to be used as an input for the jqplot (instead of the question marks).

```
echo "<div id='loggerChart1' style='height:400px;width:400px;'>";
echo "<script class='code' type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>";

echo "$.jqplot('loggerChart1',  [?????]);";
echo "</script>";
echo "</div>";
```

Thank you

Comment: And how would the prepared data look like? Comma separated strings/numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$prepared_array = ARRAY();

foreach ($plot_row1 AS $key => $value) {
  $prepared_array[] = '['.$plot_row2[$key].','.$value.']';
}
$prepared_string = '['.implode(',', $prepared_array).']';

var_dump($prepared_string);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

x-axis values (you don't have JS code for anything else, so no y-axis, captions, etc.)

```
$prepared_x_values = '[['.implode(',', $plot_row2).']]';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understands your statement about Y axis. I need the data looks like this: [[$plot_row2,$plot_row1],[$plot_row2,$plot_row1],...]  continuously from the 2 arrays...

Comment: Well, I had a "short" look on the jqPlot website... And the JS-Code there looks different for all charts I have seen.